# Ошибка при импорте пака joystick для Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d

`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Joystick : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IDragHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    public float Horizontal { get { return (snapX) ? SnapFloat(input.x, AxisOptions.Horizontal) : input.x; } }
    public float Vertical { get { return (snapY) ? SnapFloat(input.y, AxisOptions.Vertical) : input.y; } }
    public Vector2 Direction { get { return new Vector2(Horizontal, Vertical); } }

    public float HandleRange
    {
        get { return handleRange; }
        set { handleRange = Mathf.Abs(value); }
    }

    public float DeadZone
    {
        get { return deadZone; }
        set { deadZone = Mathf.Abs(value); }
    }

    public AxisOptions AxisOptions { get { return AxisOptions; } set { axisOptions = value; } }
    public bool SnapX { get { return snapX; } set { snapX = value; } }
    public bool SnapY { get { return snapY; } set { snapY = value; } }

    [SerializeField] private float handleRange = 1;
    [SerializeField] private float deadZone = 0;
    [SerializeField] private AxisOptions axisOptions = AxisOptions.Both;
    [SerializeField] private bool snapX = false;
    [SerializeField] private bool snapY = false;

    [SerializeField] protected RectTransform background = null;
    [SerializeField] private RectTransform handle = null;
    private RectTransform baseRect = null;

    private Canvas canvas;
    private Camera cam;

    private Vector2 input = Vector2.zero;

    protected virtual void Start()
    {
        HandleRange = handleRange;
        DeadZone = deadZone;
        baseRect = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        canvas = GetComponentInParent<Canvas>();
        if (canvas == null)
            Debug.LogError("The Joystick is not placed inside a canvas");

        Vector2 center = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);
        background.pivot = center;
        handle.anchorMin = center;
        handle.anchorMax = center;
        handle.pivot = center;
        handle.anchoredPosition = Vector2.zero;
    }

    public virtual void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        OnDrag(eventData);
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        cam = null;
        if (canvas.renderMode == RenderMode.ScreenSpaceCamera)
            cam = canvas.worldCamera;

        Vector2 position = RectTransformUtility.WorldToScreenPoint(cam, background.position);
        Vector2 radius = background.sizeDelta / 2;
        input = (eventData.position - position) / (radius * canvas.scaleFactor);
        FormatInput();
        HandleInput(input.magnitude, input.normalized, radius, cam);
        handle.anchoredPosition = input * radius * handleRange;
    }

    protected virtual void HandleInput(float magnitude, Vector2 normalised, Vector2 radius, Camera cam)
    {
        if (magnitude > deadZone)
        {
            if (magnitude > 1)
                input = normalised;
        }
        else
            input = Vector2.zero;
    }

    private void FormatInput()
    {
        if (axisOptions == AxisOptions.Horizontal)
            input = new Vector2(input.x, 0f);
        else if (axisOptions == AxisOptions.Vertical)
            input = new Vector2(0f, input.y);
    }

    private float SnapFloat(float value, AxisOptions snapAxis)
    {
        if (value == 0)
            return value;

        if (axisOptions == AxisOptions.Both)
        {
            float angle = Vector2.Angle(input, Vector2.up);
            if (snapAxis == AxisOptions.Horizontal)
            {
                if (angle < 22.5f || angle > 157.5f)
                    return 0;
                else
                    return (value > 0) ? 1 : -1;
            }
            else if (snapAxis == AxisOptions.Vertical)
            {
                if (angle > 67.5f && angle < 112.5f)
                    return 0;
                else
                    return (value > 0) ? 1 : -1;
            }
            return value;
        }
        else
        {
            if (value > 0)
                return 1;
            if (value < 0)
                return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public virtual void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        input = Vector2.zero;
        handle.anchoredPosition = Vector2.zero;
    }

    protected Vector2 ScreenPointToAnchoredPosition(Vector2 screenPosition)
    {
        Vector2 localPoint = Vector2.zero;
        if (RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(baseRect, screenPosition, cam, out localPoint))
        {
            Vector2 pivotOffset = baseRect.pivot * baseRect.sizeDelta;
            return localPoint - (background.anchorMax * baseRect.sizeDelta) + pivotOffset;
        }
        return Vector2.zero;
    }
}

public enum AxisOptions { Both, Horizontal, Vertical }
```

`Я импортировал joystick pack в Unity проблема в том что когда я его импортировал возникла ошибка. Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно исправить! Буду очень благодарен! [image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. Оставьте код как текст | 2.Нормально объясните суть вопроса | 3.Прежде чем сюда кидать кидайте свой вопрос в Google, Яндекс или что у вас там. | 4. Если всё же не получилось опишите что вы попробовали и как на это реагировала программа.

Comment: Смотрел в гугле подобно не нашел!

Comment: То что под вашим именем висит надпись `Новый участник` это не значит что тут вам можно делать всё. Прочитайте [как задавать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Ошибка происходит когда я имортирую файл в unity

Comment: Я добавил весь код где есть ошибка

Comment: Я с камерой не много работал но по ошибке у вас не удаётся из типа `Camera` сделать `UnityEngine.Camera`

Comment: Объекты скачанные из `Assets Store` могут содержать в себе ошибки. Попробуйте скачать другой.

Comment: Подскажите какие к примеру?)

Comment: Что вы искали, выбите в поиск эту же фразу, посмотрите у кого рейтинг выше, там не знаю комментарии читайте.

Answer (score 0):

Смог решить данную проблему переименованием скрипта камеры с Camera на Camera1, например. При этом удалил, и заново импортировал файлы джойстика